License Banner when Embedding Power BI Report
I have set up a Power BI Embedded capacity for a customer to enable them to share reports with external clients. Another company is developing a web application for them to display the reports.
The embedding works save for one minor issue: when the Power BI report is displayed in the web page, there's a grey banner saying "This is a free trial version, to remove this label a capacity must be purchased."
I'm not sure what is causing this banner to be displayed as the report is hosted in a workspace assigned to the Power BI Embedded capacity. The report dataset is hosted in a separate workspace which is not on the Embedded capacity.

What causes this banner to be displayed, and more importantly, what do I need to do to get rid of it?

To hide the banner, the Power BI Embedded capacity must be allocated to the workspace hosting the dataset. Based on our testing, when the dataset's workspace is under the capacity, the banner is removed.
